# UnicodeEncodeError, when using PyCharm to run a code sample

Tags: python, unicode, pycharm, encode, python-unicode

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Program Files/PyCharm/Projects/test.py", line 134, in <module>
    text_file.write(text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 2538: illegal multibyte sequence
```

**So basicly this was the error I met when I tried to run a code sample. My OS is not English version, which means the OS Unicode setting is the main cause.**

**I'm seeking an alternative solution to avoid these kinds of errors in PyCharm. Is there any Unicode setting in PyCharm that I can change? So I can run this code sample at my Laptop without changing the OS Unicode setting?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-file-encodings.html)?

According to PyCharm Documentation, you can set a default encoding and set it by project.